# Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:0.9.5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, libraries, build.gradle

I'm getting error, while building gradle in android studio.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.whyz.kitetech.mobile.cdrapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
      //  maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
       // maven { url "http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/maven" }
        //maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            debuggable = true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    // NOTE: vector-compat is available on API level 14 or later
    compile 'com.wnafee:vector-compat:1.0.5'
    compile 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:0.9.5'
    compile 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: use `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'`

Comment: Then clean and rebuild and gradle your project

Comment: i have changed buildToolsVersion to '23.0.1', but still its throwing error..

Comment: Please check below answer . He is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to move the repository block out side android block.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {

}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
       // maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
       // maven { url "http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/maven" }
       // maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
    }
```

Then your issue is that `de.codecrafters.tableview` **doesn't exist on Central Maven or Jcenter.**

As workaround you can use the github repo with the [**jitpack** plugin](https://jitpack.io/)

It is very simple.

Just add this repo tp your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

and the dependency:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
    }
```

In your case it seems to be:

```
 compile 'com.github.ISchwarz23:SortableTableView:v0.9.5'
```